SQL- select value from column A based on 2 values from column B. The solution should only have values from B with both values
I have a table with 2 columns A & B. I want values from A based on multiple values from B.
A     B
--   --
1    aaaa
1    bbbb
1    cccc
1    dddd
2    aaaa
3    bbbb
4    aaaa
4    bbbb
4    eeee

I want to select only values 1 and 4 in output based on values in B (i.e the column B should   have values aaaa and bbbb)
The solution required is something like this
A     B

1    aaaa
1    bbbb
4    aaaa
4    bbbb
The query I tried gives output like this
select A,B from myTable where B in ('aaaa','bbbb');
select A,B from myTable where B='aaaa' or B='bbbb' group by A,B;

Is there any column which uniquely identifies rows ?

There is no column to uniquely identify the rows

Add the DISTINCT qualifier to the SELECT clause.

Logical division.
SELECT a
FROM table 
GROUP BY a
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2


I need to display both columns and the output should have 2 entries for 1 and 2 entries for 4.

@Rixen My query provides needed a values for you. Use it as subquery, join to another table cpopy and select complete needed rows.

I tried the query in sub query and it's giving all rows for 1 and 4 A B 1 aaaa 1 bbbb 1 cccc 1 dddd 4 aaaa 4 bbbb 4 eeee   The query I tried is like this SELECT A,B FROM myTable  where A in(SELECT a FROM myTable  GROUP BY a HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2);

SELECT A,B FROM myTable  where A in(SELECT a FROM myTable  GROUP BY a HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2);

A B 1 aaaa 1 bbbb 1 cccc 1 dddd 4 aaaa 4 bbbb 4 eeee

@Rixen o_O WHERE b IN ('aaaa', 'bbbb') obviously must be added to outer query...

Use a subquery to retrieve matching values from A column and the JOIN with the main table
SELECT m.A,m.B
FROM myTable m
INNER JOIN (SELECT A
            FROM myTable 
            WHERE B in ('aaaa','bbbb')
            GROUP BY A
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 2 
           ) sub on sub.A = m.A
WHERE B in ('aaaa','bbbb') ;
#GROUP BY m.A,m.B;

Add GROUP BY clause for duplicates, such as aaaa 1 twice and so on.

Instead of JOIN you could use IN
SELECT m.A,m.B
FROM myTable m
WHERE A IN (SELECT A
            FROM myTable 
            WHERE B in ('aaaa','bbbb')
            GROUP BY A
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B) = 2 )
AND B in ('aaaa','bbbb')
#GROUP BY m.A,m.B;


Thank you this works as per my need.

You can do this by using an analytic function, like so:
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 a, 'aaaa' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 a, 'bbbb' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 a, 'cccc' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 a, 'dddd' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 a, 'aaaa' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 a, 'bbbb' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 a, 'aaaa' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 a, 'bbbb' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 a, 'eeee' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 a, 'aaaa' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 a, 'aaaa' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 a, 'bbbb' b FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 a, 'bbbb' b FROM dual),
   -- end of mimicking your table
   base_results AS (SELECT a,
                           b,
                           CASE WHEN b = 'aaaa' THEN 1
                                WHEN b = 'bbbb' THEN 2
                           END col_vals
                    FROM   your_table),
    mid_results AS (SELECT a,
                           b,
                           COUNT(DISTINCT col_vals) OVER (PARTITION BY a) cnt,
                           SUM(col_vals) OVER (PARTITION BY a) tot
                    FROM   base_results
                    WHERE  col_vals IS NOT NULL)
SELECT a, b
FROM   mid_results
WHERE  cnt = 2;

         A B
---------- ----
         1 aaaa
         1 bbbb
         4 aaaa
         4 bbbb
         5 aaaa
         5 aaaa
         5 bbbb
         5 bbbb

N.B. I've assumed here that your b column isn't unique and that if there were two rows or more of either aaaa and/or bbbb that you would wish to display the rows (e.g. where a = 5 is a valid output), but if that's not the case, then change the final where clause to be where tot = 3. You can remove whichever analytic function you don't need from the query.
Also note that I separated out the base_results and mid_results subqueries into two queries to avoid needing to type out the case statement more than once, but you could combine these into a single query if you don't mind repeating that logic more than once.
